# Convert string to array from ElementValue

Tags: java, arrays

I want to convert element which is hold is array of type ElementValue:

https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-bcel/apidocs/org/apache/bcel/classfile/ElementValue.html

```
ElementValue c = item.getElementNameValuePair().getValue();
System.out.println(c.stringifyValue());
```

This prints `[Example author 1,Example author 2]` How I can convert it into array of Strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You make sure `c` is an array, then you stringify each value of that array.

```
if (c.getElementValueType() == ElementValue.ARRAY) {
    ElementValue[] evArray = ((ArrayElementValue) c).getElementValuesArray();
    String[] strArray = new String[evArray.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < evArray.length; i++)
        strArray[i] = evArray[i].stringifyValue();
}
```